# Tmux pane current command

Tags: tmux, pane, mintty

i have started using tmux recent past . So far so good .

while exploring the option , i found an option as

```
#Enable names for panes
    set -g pane-border-status top   --> I see this as working with no issue.
    #Automatically assign a name
    set -g pane-border-format "#P: #{pane_current_command}"  --> This is command is not per my expectation
```

I log into terminal where i enabled the tmux , and then i log onto a taxi server and then to my application server. My expectation is when i going aound the paths on my app server , i want the pane window to show that path .

can some one help me ? if any other command you as well would be great.

wanted to let you know -

i have tried modifying .bashrc as well . It is working fine , if i am using putty , but not while on tmux.

I am using tmux on windows machine i.e., mintty ( not on ubuntu , mac x )

Comment: I think it is not possible. `tmux` can only show the current running command. It will be just `bash` in the title in your case.

Comment: that is right , i see the same . Thank you responding .                                    Do you think , is there a way that i can change on bottom right  ( i forgot the name , but it is where the date is shown ? ) to display the pwd stats?

Comment: It's status-right. You can configure it in your own way. Checkout my [tmux.conf](https://github.com/arpitjindal97/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf). See the 18th line. I guess you can do it yourself now. Add `#(pwd)` somehwere

Comment: But why add `pwd`. Bash already shows the path